# Is direct data ingestion from pub/sub to memorystore possible?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-memorystore

I was wondering if there's any possible option to move data directly from Pub/Sub to Memorystore, no mather Redis or Memcached. Is there any kind of subscription from Memorystore to Pub/Sub?

I'm trying to move data directly from Pub/Sub to Memorystore. Could that be possible?
At first sight I see:

- Memorystore subscription to Pub/Sub
- Dataflow to write to Memorystore

Am I crazy? Is one of those options possible? Any other possible option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no direct connection between PubSub and memorystore. You must set up a processing layer between the 2.

It could be Dataflow as you mention, but also a lightweight/serverless solution like Cloud Run or Cloud Functions.